# Existence of probability measure

Tags: probability-theory

> **Exercise**
>
> Let $\mathcal G$ be a $\sigma$-field of subsets of a non-empty set $\Omega$, show there exists a probability measure $P$ on ($\Omega,\mathcal G$)

Can someone give me hint on this question? Can I use Lebesgue measure in this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know if $\ \ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}, \  $ so we can't simply use Lebesgue measure. Even if we would have $\ \Omega=[0,1], \ \ $ there possibly can be some $ \ V \in \mathcal{G}, \  $ that is not Lebesgue measurable - see for instance the Vitali set.

But we know, that $\Omega$ is not empty. So let us choose any $\omega \in \Omega$ and put
$$\mathbb{P}:\mathcal{G} \mapsto [0,1],$$
$$\forall \ \  G\in \mathcal{G} \ : \ \ \mathbb{P}(G)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & \textrm{if  $ \  \ \ \omega \in G,$}\\
0 & \textrm{if  $\ \  \omega \not \in G,$}
\end{array} \right. $$

It is straightforward to check  that axioms of probability are satisfied.